# Is there a function in google apps spreadsheetapp to save the activeSpreadsheet as another name(Duplicating)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very new to google appts scripts and was wondering is there is a way to easily duplicate the activeSpreadsheet and save it by another name?  I think I see a path to do it by using getvalues or getsheetvalues and using the create function to make the file.  I just wanted to know if I am making this more difficult then it should be?

Comment: Is this question about duplicating a spreadsheet or a sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function copyActiveSheetToNewSheet() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet().copyTo(ss);
}
```

New Name is "Copy of " + ss.getActiveSheet().getName();

Comment: I really appreciate it my friend.